# What can cause rent prices to fall?

Tags: rent, rental-property

In the 2007 Global Finanical Crisis many places like the US, Ireland and Europe, experienced a popping of their housing bubble and as a result, house prices dropped quite a lot.

However, as most people still needed to live in houses and living in a house would the last thing people sacrificed, rent prices did not really fall. That is, that house prices fell to meet rent price levels, but rent price levels did not change.

My question is if a large recession doesn't cause rent prices to drop, do rents ever fall? Can anyone think of an example historically where there was a "rent price" crash?

I'm ruling out any example caused by a large scale disaster like Chernobyl or a devastating earthquake.

In other words, I'm interested in only examples where the rented property and it's surroundings were in the same physical state before and after the rent drop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure!

Anything that affects the balance of supply and demand could cause rent prices to fall. I'll betcha rent prices in Wilmington, Ohio collapsed when the biggest employer, DHL, [shut down](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/09/18/us-usa-economy-jobless-idUSTRE58H0PH20090918). An economic depression of any sort would cause people to substitute expensive rentals for cheaper ones, putting downward pressure on rents. It would also cause people to double up or move in with family, decreasing demand for rentals.

Anything that makes buying a house cheaper will actually make rents lower, too, because more people will buy houses when houses get cheaper... those people are moving out of rentals, thus decreasing demand for rentals.

Comment: mmm that's a good point, i never took into account rent crashes within just a small area like a town. Do you know if overall cost of renting in the US has fallen? I haven't seen any research indicating this.

Comment: It's trivial to find out... All the data is published by the US Bureau of Labor Statistics. The number you want is called [Consumer Price Indexes for Rent and Rental Equivalence](http://www.bls.gov/cpi/cpifact6.htm) and the data is [here](http://www.economagic.com/blscu.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The buy-to-rent investment bubble created (in some markets) a large number of new housing starts often exceeding the available demand.  Since people were investing in the capital gain, they didn't mind whether a place was rented or not.  Many places stood empty at the prices investors wished to charge.

In the UK where building restrictions are so dire that few new houses can be built, new house production is less than market demand which keeps up rental prices.  There just isn't any stock.

In the US, where construction is more liberal, rental prices can fall as new stock enters the market.  A driver will be where the sales market dries up and owners must rent to cover at least some of their mortgage losses. Or, as Joel points out, if a major employer which dominates a small town, leaves.  Many old industrial towns feature both low rentals and plenty of empty, low-priced property.  Liverpool, in the UK, features entire empty neighbourhoods all boarded up.

If you're looking to track metrics on this simply look at migration patterns.  Where large numbers of people are moving "towards" prices (and rentals) will rise.  Where people are moving "away" all prices fall.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the government effectively sets a price floor for rents with a concept called "prevailing rent" for government subsidy. Even the crappiest, minimally compliant hovel is ultimately worth whatever the government will issue housing vouchers for.

Rent can and does fluctuate for the higher end of the market. Basically in most places the available, cheap credit has a negative impact on rent prices, and tighter, costlier credit increases demand and rents. Local economic events have an impact too. If the company closes in a company town, people leave.

Answer (score 0):

In Memphis, Tn., rents were stabilized from falling in the recession because all the foreclosed on home owners added to the rental market, increasing demand and thus stabilizing pricing.